# Как узнать высоту строки RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Изображение]

Как я могу узнать высоту строки в элементе RichTextBox используя средства C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гугл подсказывает что можно сделать следующий костыль.

К примеру у нас есть такой текст :

```
"hello\nworld"
```

Определим Y кординату курсора на второй строчке

```
var y1 = myRichText.GetPositionFromCharIndex(6).Y;
```

Определим Y кординату курсора на первой строчке

```
var y2 = myRichText.GetPositionFromCharIndex(5).Y;
```

посчитаем высоту

```
var height = y1 - y2;
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал)

Comment: У тебя ошибка - worLd)

Comment: Сейчас исправлю ошибку:) код работает? я его не тестировал

Comment: Момент.........

Comment: Работает как часы)

Comment: @Андрей - Гм, полагаю, есть нюанс: это нормально работает, если в строке только текст одним шрифтом. А ведь могут быть разные слова разными шрифтами. А ещё картинка может быть вставлена...

Comment: Мне это не грозит)